# How to track the values of a variable during execution in Python?

Tags: python, data-structure

Assume I have access to the following Python module (foo.py) that was written by someone else (let's call her Ann):

```
import libX
libX.doSomething()

for i in range(10):
    a = i + 3
b = foo()
```

I am the creator of `libX`, which Ann uses in her code.

What I am trying to do is to **automatically** track some variables (and their values) inside Ann's code during execution. For example, I want my `doSomehting()` function to be able to track the values of the variables `a` and `b` and send them to some visualization tool -during the execution of `foo.py`.

My `doSomehting()` function can already locate and identify the variables that I am interested in using Python AST (Abstract Syntax Tree).

Ann's code and my library are both written in Python.

What tool's or techniques do you recommend to accomplish this task?